# How to hide div slowly using jquery with exploting effect

Tags: jquery

I am New in programing Please help Me to 
hide div slowly using jquery with exploting effect

Comment: All you need is here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Explode

Comment: And here: (download the demo I created) http://jsbin.com/iyuvac/1/edit

Comment: This is pretty much asking for code without any research, I would request this be closed as low quality if I thought it would happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
$("#divId").hide('explode',1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery("#some_id").hide("explode", 5000);
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Explode

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 1):

To hide

```
 $("#divId").hide('explode',1000);
```

To show

```
$("#divId").show('explode',1000);
```